# xml xsl node selection based on attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to select a sibling node based on attribute value. The related part of the xml look like,

```
<wd:Job_Classifications>
    <wd:Job_Classification_ID>20</wd:Job_Classification_ID>
    <wd:Job_Classification_Group wd:Descriptor="SUS Occupational Categories">              
        <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Classification_Group_ID">SUS_OCC_CATEGORIES</wd:ID>        
    </wd:Job_Classification_Group>    
</wd:Job_Classifications>

<wd:Job_Classifications>   
    <wd:Job_Classification_ID>9009</wd:Job_Classification_ID>        
    <wd:Job_Classification_Group wd:Descriptor="SUS Classification Code">                
        <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Classification_Group_ID">SUS_CLASS_CODE</wd:ID>        
    </wd:Job_Classification_Group>    
</wd:Job_Classifications>

<wd:Job_Classifications>    
    <wd:Job_Classification_ID>99</wd:Job_Classification_ID>
    <wd:Job_Classification_Group wd:Descriptor="Administrative Code">                
        <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Classification_Group_ID">ADMIN_CODE</wd:ID>        
    </wd:Job_Classification_Group>    
</wd:Job_Classifications>
```

And the xsl I am trying is like

```
<xsl:value-of select="../wd:Job_Classifications
                      [@wd:Descriptor
                      ='SUS Classification Code']
                      /wd:Job_Classification_ID" />
```

which gives me no result. I am inside a two level for loop and had to use ../ to get to immediate parent.
When I use the below,

```
<xsl:value-of select="../wd:Job_Classifications
                      /wd:Job_Classification_ID" />
```

I get all the IDs but I need to select based on wd:Job_Classification_Group descriptor value.

Comment: You should add more of your XSLT, and provide a valid XML in input. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're applying the predicate `[@wd:Descriptor ='SUS Classification Code']` to an element named `wd:Job_Classifications`, but the only `wd:Job_Classifications` element in your XML has no attribute of that or any other name.

Perhaps you mean `../wd:Job_Classifications [wd:Job_Classification_Group /@wd:Descriptor='SUS Classification Code'] /wd:Job_Classification_ID` ?

Comment: Thank you C.M. Sperberg-McQueen. I corrected the way you specified and it is now returning the IDs. I did not know how to write that predicate. I was trying something like "<xsl:value-of select="../wd:Job_Classifications/wd:Job_Classification_Group[@wd:Descriptor = 'SUS Classification Code']"></xsl:value-of>" but was not able to trace back to ID as the ID was not nested inside the group. I really appreciate your help as I was trying for 2 days to resolve this before posting it.